# I need to save images from a directory to another and i fall in a infinity loop

Tags: javascript, html

This is for a image treatment in a canvas, i'll put one image like a mockup over the others came from a directory but, somehow i create a infinity loop...
So how did i screw up?

```
function SaveAjax(dataURL){
  window.setInterval(function(){
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "saveImage.php",
      data: { 
         imgBase64: dataURL
      }
    }).done(function(o) {
      // console.log('saved');
    });
  })
}

function loadFile(f) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onloadend = function () {
        var arte = new Image();
        arte.crossOrigin = "anonymous";
        arte.onload = function(){
            context.drawImage(arte, 0, 0, 1200, 1200)
            var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
            SaveAjax(dataURL);
        }
        arte.src = reader.result;

        // images.push({
        //     name : f.name, // use whatever naming magic you prefer here
        //     image : reader.result
        // });
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(f);
}

$(":file").change(function(event) {
    var files = this.files;

    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        loadFile(files[i]);
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

`window.setInterval` is a function that will call whatever you provide every set number of milliseconds. Each `SaveAjax()` call you make will be repeated, I believe every 1ms, with the same data. Change it to [`window.setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/setTimeout) which will run your ajax request just once after set number of milliseconds.

Comment: English version of the link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout

Comment: Maannnn i'm a idiot! haha, i paste the ajax function and forgot to delete the setInterval, thank you !

Comment: But still dont saving all the images =(